# Grails 5 deploy error on Wildfly and Websphere

Tags: grails, websphere, wildfly, micronaut

Grails 5.3.2, Grails 5.2.6

Created an application with both of the grails versions mentioned above and tried to deploy the war file on Wildfly 24 and Websphere 8.5. With either grails version build, it failed on each application server at the time of deployment with error message as below:

```
Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test526.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test526.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventPublisher<io.micronaut.context.event.StartupEvent>] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventPublisher<io.micronaut.context.event.StartupEvent>] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventPublisher<io.micronaut.context.event.StartupEvent>] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2790)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1602)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:865)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanLocator.getBean(BeanLocator.java:94)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.publishEvent(DefaultBeanContext.java:1688)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:354)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:190)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.createApplicationContext(GrailsApp.groovy:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    ... 10 more
```

Micronaut dependency is not our required dependency, it is required by grails.

I tried different versions varying from grails 5.2.0 to 5.3.2 (latest stable release at the time). Build with these versions throw the same error.

Is it bug with grails stable releases or is there something needs to be taken care when we build war using `gradle assemble` or any configuration we needed on application server side ?

Build created with grails 5.1.10 and earlier are able to deploy on these servers without any issue (except removing transitive dependencies of Tomcat).

Comment: Anyone can please guide how to get rid of this error? I think this is related to class loading issue?, because the class it is complaining about is already under the WAR's lib directory. The NoSuchBeanException complains about bean is not there in the container means the container has not initialized the bean properly? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Did you find the error?